# What is the automorphism group of $D_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

First $p > 2$ be prime, I guess that the order of the automorphism group of $D_p$ is $p(p-1)$. I want to prove by using the proof of the classification of groups of order $2p$, but I fail. I'd like to ask for some ideas?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Since you say you have a conjecture about the order of the automorphism group I assume that you have a conjecture about what the auto group is. Why not edit the question to give details and to say why you think there may be other automorphisms.

Comment: Hint. The group $D_p$ contains a unique cyclic group $C_p$ (which is the subset of all elements $x$ such that $x^p=1$). Every automorphism of $D_p$ induces an automorphism of $C_p$ and is completely determined by the automorphism of $C_p$ and by the image of a given element $s \in D_p \setminus C_p$.

Comment: I think the answer to this question is also in the MSE, but I couldn't find it. But the answer is in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group#Automorphism_group).